# Complex numbers (Polar form)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What is the polar form of $-4+4i$?

I am getting argument as negative $45^{\circ}$.

So is $-45^{\circ}$ my final argument?

Comment: Wrong direction for negative angles. $-45^\circ$ is in the fourth quadrant. Your point is in the second quadrant.

Comment: The correct method is described here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/256333

Answer (score 1):

The modulus gives you the radius so 
$$
r=\sqrt{16+16}=4\sqrt{2}
$$
And your angle is given by 
$$
\arctan(-1)=-\pi/4
$$
Then you need to see what quadrant you are in, which in your case is negative real and positive imaginary components, so in the second quadrant, yielding an addition of $\pi$ and an argument of $3\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1):

Angle or argument is in second quadrant $( x <0, y>0)$. The angle is found from atan2 function which is sensitive to sign of x,y components, placing it in second quadrant. If not careful you may end up in the fourth quadrant choice.

$$ (+,+)\rightarrow Q1;\, (-,+)\rightarrow  Q2; \, (-,-)\rightarrow Q3 ; \, Q(+,-)\rightarrow Q4\,$$

So in polar  form

$$ r e^{i \theta}  = 4 \sqrt 2 e^{i\,3 \pi/4 }. $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+yi$ , so $x=-4$ and $y=4$ .

Magnitude of $z$ is given by $r=|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{16+16}=4\sqrt{2}$

Since $x<0$ and $y\ge 0$ the argument of $z$ is given by $\varphi=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})+\pi =-\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ .

Comment: So when all do you have to add  pie

Comment: @user362711 See this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form

Comment: @user362711 You are welcome ..