# Real part of $ \quad 1- \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta}).$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

To solve the Dirichlet problem  using mellin transform, i needed to find the real part of $ \quad 1- \displaystyle\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta}).$
I already know the result will be
\begin{cases}
\quad 1- \displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{2r^{\rho}\cos(\rho \theta)}{1-r^{2\rho}}) & \text{ si } r\in [0, 1]\\ \quad \\
\quad  \displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{2r^{\rho}\cos(\rho \theta)}{r^{2\rho}-1}) & \text{ si } r\in ]1,+\infty[.\\
\end{cases}
I find it in "Dautray R., Lions J.L.,  Mathematical analysis and numerical calculation for science and technology."

I want to know how they found it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complex number $z \ne \pm \mathrm{i}$, we have
$$\arctan z = \frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\ln \frac{\mathrm{i} - z}{\mathrm{i} + z}$$
where $\ln u$ is the principal branch of complex logarithm ($u\ne 0$)
$$\ln u = \ln |u| + \mathrm{i}\arg u, \quad -\pi < \arg u \le \pi.$$
(See, e.g. [http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf))

Also, if $c, d$ are real numbers with $c^2 + d^2 \ne 0$, we have
$$\arg (c + d\mathrm{i}) = 
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
 \arctan \frac{d}{c} & c > 0 \\[5pt]
 \arctan \frac{d}{c} + \pi & c < 0, d \ge 0 \\[5pt]
 \arctan \frac{d}{c} - \pi & c < 0, d < 0\\[5pt]
 \frac{\pi}{2} & c = 0, d > 0\\[5pt]
 -\frac{\pi}{2} & c = 0, d < 0
\end{array}
\right.$$
See, e.g. [How to figure out the Argument of complex number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256236/how-to-figure-out-the-argument-of-complex-number)

$\phantom{2}$

Consider the case when $r > 0$ and $\rho > 0$.

Let $a = r^\rho \cos \rho\theta$
and $b = r^\rho \sin \rho\theta$.
Then $a^2 + b^2 = r^{2\rho}$.

(1) If $0 < r < 1$, we have
$$\mathrm{Re} [\arctan (a + b\mathrm{i})]
= \mathrm{Re} \left(\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\ln \frac{1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2a \mathrm{i}}{a^2 + (1 + b)^2}\right) = \frac12 \arctan \frac{2a}{1 - a^2 - b^2}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\mathrm{Re}\left(1- \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta})\right)
= 1 - \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan \frac{2r^\rho \cos \rho\theta}{1 - r^{2\rho}}.$$

(2) If $r > 1$ and $a \ge 0$, we have
$$\mathrm{Re} [\arctan (a + b\mathrm{i})]
= \mathrm{Re} \left(\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\ln \frac{1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2a \mathrm{i}}{a^2 + (1 + b)^2} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac12 \arctan \frac{2a}{a^2 + b^2 - 1}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\mathrm{Re}\left(1- \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta})\right)
= \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan \frac{2r^\rho \cos \rho\theta}{r^{2\rho} - 1}.$$

(3) If $r > 1$ and $a < 0$, we have
$$\mathrm{Re} [\arctan (a + b\mathrm{i})]
= \mathrm{Re} \left(\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\ln \frac{1 - a^2 - b^2 + 2a \mathrm{i}}{a^2 + (1 + b)^2} \right) = \frac12 \arctan \frac{2a}{1 - a^2 - b^2} - \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\mathrm{Re}\left(1- \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta})\right)
= 2 - \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan \frac{ - 2 r^\rho \cos \rho\theta}{r^{2\rho} - 1}.$$

(4) If $r = 1$ and $a > 0$, we have
$$\mathrm{Re} [\arctan (a + b\mathrm{i})]
= \mathrm{Re} \left(\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\ln \frac{2a \mathrm{i}}{a^2 + (1 + b)^2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\mathrm{Re}\left(1- \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta})\right)
= \frac12.$$

(5) If $r = 1$ and $a < 0$, we have
$$\mathrm{Re} [\arctan (a + b\mathrm{i})]
= \mathrm{Re} \left(\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\ln \frac{2a \mathrm{i}}{a^2 + (1 + b)^2}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\mathrm{Re}\left(1- \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta})\right)
= \frac32.$$

We are done.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now, in the second case the argument is $\pi-\arctan \frac{2a}{a^2 + b^2 - 1}$ could you explain more, when we give to the argument $\arctan \frac{\Im(z)}{\Re(z)}$ and when it's equal to $\pi-\arctan  \frac{\Im(z)}{\Re(z)}$ for what condition ?

Comment: @EDABABYOUSSEF No problem. I will edit.

Comment: @EDABABYOUSSEF I made some mistakes. I edited.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you so much @River-Li

Comment: @EDABABYOUSSEF You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You could solve the equation

$$1-\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta}) = a+bi$$

where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

To do this, rearrange the equation:

$$\begin{align}
1-\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta}) &= a+bi \\
\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta}) &= 1-a-bi \\
\arctan(r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta}) &= \frac{\pi}{2}(1-a)-i\frac{\pi b}{2} \\
r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta} &= \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-a)-i\frac{\pi b}{2}\right) \\
r^{\rho}(\cos(\rho\theta)+i\sin(\rho\theta)) &= \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-a)-i\frac{\pi b}{2}\right) \quad (*)
\end{align}$$

Then you can split the right side into its real and imaginary parts using the following facts:

$$\begin{align}
(1)& \ \tan(x-y) = \frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)} \\
(2)& \ \tan(ix) = i\tanh(x) \\
(3)& \ \frac{x-iy}{1+ixy} = \frac{(x-iy)(1-ixy)}{(1+ixy)(1-ixy)} = \frac{x-iy-ix^2y-xy^2}{1+x^2y^2} = \\ &= \frac{x-xy^2}{1+x^2y^2} + i\frac{y+x^2y}{1+x^2y^2}
\end{align}$$

So let

$$\begin{align}
A &:= \frac{\pi}{2}(1-a) \\
B &:= \frac{\pi b}{2}
\end{align}$$

With this substituion

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-a)-i\frac{\pi b}{2}\right) = \tan\left(A-iB\right) \stackrel{(1)}{=} \\ \stackrel{(1)}{=} \frac{\tan(A)-\tan(iB)}{1+\tan(A)\tan(iB)} \stackrel{(2)}{=} \frac{\tan(A)-i\tanh(B)}{1+i\tan(A)\tanh(B)} \stackrel{(3)}{=} \\ \stackrel{(3)}{=} \frac{\tan(A)-\tan(A)\tanh(B)^2}{1+\tan(A)^2\tanh(B)^2} + i\frac{\tanh(B)+\tan(A)^2\tanh(B)}{1+\tan(A)^2\tanh(B)^2}$$

We know that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, so $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$, which means that the expression we just obtained is in the form

$$(\text{real number}) + i(\text{real number})$$

That means we can pair up the first and second real numbers with what we got in $(*)$:

$$\begin{align}
\text{I. } r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta) &= \frac{\tan(A)-\tan(A)\tanh(B)^2}{1+\tan(A)^2\tanh(B)^2} \\
\text{II. } r^{\rho}\sin(\rho\theta) &= \frac{\tanh(B)+\tan(A)^2\tanh(B)}{1+\tan(A)^2\tanh(B)^2}
\end{align}$$

Now we just need to solve these for $A$ and $B$, then substitue back $A = \frac{\pi}{2}(1-a) \leftrightarrow a = 1-\frac{2}{\pi}A$ to find the real part of the original expression.

Let

$$\begin{align}
T &:= \tan(A) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-a)\right) \\
H &:= \tanh(B) = \tanh\left(\frac{\pi b}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Then we can rewrite the above equations to

$$\begin{align}
\text{I. } r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta) &= \frac{T-TH^2}{1+T^2H^2} = T\left(\frac{1-H^2}{1+T^2H^2}\right) \\
\text{II. } r^{\rho}\sin(\rho\theta) &= \frac{H+T^2H}{1+T^2H^2} = H\left(\frac{1+T^2}{1+T^2H^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Then since $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, no matter what $x$ is,

$$\begin{align}
r^{2\rho} &= r^{2\rho}(\sin^2(\rho\theta)+\cos^2(\rho\theta)) = \\ &= 
T^2\left(\frac{(1-H^2)^2}{(1+T^2H^2)^2}\right) + H^2\left(\frac{(1+T^2)^2}{(1+T^2H^2)^2}\right) = \\ &= 
\frac{1}{(1+T^2H^2)^2}\left(T^2(1-2H^2+H^4)+H^2(1+2T^2+T^4)\right) = \\ &= 
\frac{T^2-2T^2 H^2+T^2 H^4+H^2+2T^2 H^2+H^2 T^4}{(1+T^2 H^2)^2} = \\ &=
\frac{T^2+T^2 H^4+H^2+H^2 T^4}{(1+T^2 H^2)^2} = \\ &=
\frac{T^2(1+T^2 H^2)+H^2(1+T^2 H^2)}{(1+T^2 H^2)^2} = \\ &=
\frac{(T^2+H^2)(1+T^2 H^2)}{(1+T^2 H^2)^2} = \frac{T^2+H^2}{1+T^2 H^2}
\end{align}$$

From here we can express $H$ from $T$:

$$\begin{align}
T^2+H^2 &= r^{2\rho}(1+T^2H^2) \\
T^2+H^2 &= r^{2\rho}+r^{2\rho}T^2H^2 \\
T^2-r^{2\rho} &= r^{2\rho}T^2H^2-H^2 \\
T^2-r^{2\rho} &= H^2(r^{2\rho}T^2-1) \\
\frac{T^2-r^{2\rho}}{r^{2\rho}T^2-1} &= H^2 \\
\end{align}$$

Then substitute it back to $\text{I.}$:

$$\begin{align}
r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta) &= T\left(\frac{1-H^2}{1+T^2H^2}\right) = \\
&= T\left(\frac{1-\frac{T^2-r^{2\rho}}{r^{2\rho}T^2-1}}{1+T^2\left(\frac{T^2-r^{2\rho}}{r^{2\rho}T^2-1}\right)}\right) = \\
&= T\left(\frac{\frac{r^{2\rho}T^2-1-T^2+r^{2\rho}}{r^{2\rho}T^2-1}}{\frac{r^{2\rho}T^2-1+T^2(T^2-r^{2\rho})}{r^{2\rho}T^2-1}}\right) = \\
&= T\left(\frac{r^{2\rho}T^2-1-T^2+r^{2\rho}}{r^{2\rho}T^2-1+T^4-T^2r^{2\rho}}\right) = \\
&= T\left(\frac{r^{2\rho}(T^2+1)-(T^2+1)}{T^4-1}\right) = \\
&= T\left(\frac{(T^2+1)(r^{2\rho}-1)}{(T^2+1)(T^2-1)}\right) = \\
&= T\left(\frac{r^{2\rho}-1}{T^2-1}\right)
\end{align}$$

And solve it for $T$:

$$\begin{align}
r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta) &= T\left(\frac{r^{2\rho}-1}{T^2-1}\right) \\
(T^2-1)r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta) &= T(r^{2\rho}-1) \\
T^2r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta)-T(r^{2\rho}-1)-r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta) &= 0
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
T_{1,2} &= \frac{r^{2\rho}-1 \pm \sqrt{(r^{2\rho}-1)^2+4r^{2\rho}\cos^2(\rho\theta)}}{2r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta)} = \\
&= \frac{r^{2\rho}-1}{2r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta)} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{r^{2\rho}-1}{2r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta)}\right)^2+1}
\end{align}$$

Finally, solve everything for the real part of the original expression, $a$. Since $T = \tan(A) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-a)\right)$, then $a = 1-\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(T)$:

$$a_{1,2} = 1-\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{r^{2\rho}-1}{2r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta)} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{r^{2\rho}-1}{2r^{\rho}\cos(\rho\theta)}\right)^2+1}\right)$$

Depending on the input $r$, either the $+$ or the $-$ solution is selected. For this, you'd also need to calculate $H$ by substituting the $T$ we've obtained into $\text{II.}$, then finding $b$ from $H$ usng $b_{1,2} = \frac{2}{\pi}\tan(H_{1,2})$. Then check for which $a_k+b_ki, \ i \in \{1,2\}$ the original equation holds.

Comment: That's helpful, I get it,  thank you so much  @Daniel-P